# No sound in lenovo yoga 2 except when connected to HDMI

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, hdmi, lenovo-laptop

I recently got a Lenovo Yoga 2 with windows 8 (now upgraded to windows 10), and apparently sound doesn't work; not through speakers, not through headphones, but only through HDMI.

I have looked all over the internet, tried all kinds of fixes, uninstalled, reinstalled, and updated drivers, tried other drivers, and device manager says that everything works fine. I want to try use Ubuntu to see if that'll work, but never used ubuntu on a tablet nor ever tried installing it on a tablet, so I am unsure in that area.

Anything you guys might help me with?

Without HDMI:

[image]

With HDMI:

[image]

Comment: Can you check if there are any exclamation marks in device manager?

Comment: @AndroidDev There are none.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the audio drivers from Lenovo's website?

Comment: @AndroidDev yep. Multiple times even.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a picture of what shows up when you click the audio icon in the system tray, both with the HDMI connected, and without.

Comment: Probably a defective device. Warranty? HDMI audio is usually separate as it has to tie in with Video.

Comment: @D_Zab I actually bought it used. The previous owners thought it was too compex, so they only used it for an hour, and then it has just been lying in a drawer for half a year. Could it be because of the magnetic keyboard being on the speakers and that area for so long?

Comment: @AndroidDev I added pictures.

Comment: What is the default sound device, HDMI?

Comment: @Moab I honestly don't know, and if so, I have no idea how to direct it to the speakers and headphone jack :v

Comment: Control Panel>Sounds>Playback Tab, what is the default device? green check on it?

Comment: @Moab Yep, there's a green check on it.

Comment: Green check on what device?

Comment: @Moab Instel SST Audio device (WDM). That is the speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I consider if the driver of your sound card is not compatible with Windows 10, have you tried to install in compatibility mode?

To install in compatibility mode do the following:

Right click the installer>Choose Properties>Under Compatibility tab>Choose OS

If still not work, let's see the setupapi.dev.log to see the details as below:
under %windir%\inf, locate the device and find the line below:

dvi:           Rank         - 0x00000000

Then, corresponds the score in this link: 
 
Identifier Score
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546297(v=vs.85).aspx

The score near 0x00003FFF means that the driver and device may not compatible with current system.

Comment: First one didn't work.

The rank there is 0x00ff0001, and I am not really understanding what that means.